# Consuming a Webservice from a Console Application

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

I have a web service that creates a JSON package (or whatever you want to call it) like this:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void MyMethod(string letters, int number)
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                //Do some stuff here

                result.Add("data1", 1);
                result.Add("data2", "second value");

                JavaScriptSerializer s= new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Context.Response.Clear();
                Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                Context.Response.Flush();
                Context.Response.Write(s.Serialize(result));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

When I test it I get a nice response like the following:
{"data1":1,"data2":"second value."}

Now, the problem is that I've deployed it to a test server and created a simple console application to try make it work. Here's the application that tries to consume the service. Consider that I added a web reference and named it MyWS, so the namespace and the class have the same name (not what's causing the problem):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyWS.MyWS x = new MyWS.MyWS ();
            x.Timeout = 5000;
            try
            {
                x.MyMethod("Hello World", 1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
```

When I run this, I know the web service has been reached. The "Do some stuff here" part in the WS writes to a database. It does that, no problem there, so the problem must be after that.

The only error I get is a code 500 with no real meaning. Looking around I've found that it could be the .Flush() method, so I deleted that line, and that the Context.Response.BufferOutput should be set to true. Did that, didn't work.

Oh, and (probably) to make things worse, the WS will be later consumed by an Android App. But first things first: What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than just ignoring your `catch` on the server why don't you log the exception and tell us what it says? Error `500` means internal server error and normally has a message associated with it. Error handling is key when doing client / server stuff!

Comment: The catch doesn't apply here. What I mean is if I debug step by step the console application and enter the method, I can go all the way without reaching the catch block. It goes on, but when it normally exits the web method, I get the exception in the `main` function, and what it says is that _the response is not a proper XML code_. It shouldn't be, it's supposed to be JSON, so the console application should expect it as such. In any case, the error happens between the response sent by the web service and it being received by the application. Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed it a bit, but the response I get is the actual page that is displayed when I run the web service and it opens in the browser, meaning I'm getting the actual HTML code it generates when I press F5 to run it. I'm posting the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I found the solution on my own after all... well, still browsing the Internet. Here's the code that works. Nevermind the variable names in Spanish (I'm Mexican living in Mexico City). By the way, I found the solution in a forum in Spanish, so it pays off to learn more that your native language. =) It's all inside the Main method of the console application.

```
string datos = "";

    string url = "http://server.com/wsDirectory/wsFile.asmx/MethodName?param1=value1&param2=value2";
    string respuesta = "";

    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(datos);
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest solicitud = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        solicitud.Method = "GET";
        solicitud.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse r = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)solicitud.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream datosRespuesta = r.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader lector = new System.IO.StreamReader(datosRespuesta);
        respuesta = lector.ReadToEnd();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializador = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> resultado = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializador.Deserialize<object>(respuesta);
        Console.Write("Resultado obtenido: " + resultado.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```